# Using a different input for filtering using Smart Table

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have been trying to wire up an input to the filtering functionality of the Smart Table without using the built in input that shows up when `isGlobalSearchActivated`. I have asked the creator of Smart Table if this is possible, but have not heard back from him after a few days. Do any of you guys know of an easy way to do this besides restyling the default input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dig into the Smart-Table.debug.js file you will find this bit of code:

```
angular.module("partials/globalSearchCell.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("partials/globalSearchCell.html",
    "<div class=\"pull-left form-group\">\n" +
    "  <input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"Search\" ng-model=\"searchValue\"/ style=\"margin: 0;\">\n" +
    "</div>");
}]);
```

Put whatever you want in there as an input as long as it has `ng-model` pointing to `searchValue`.

If your situation is more complicated than that, let me know.